# Quartz Scheduler automatic Stop on IIS 7

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I have used Quartz .Net library for Scheduling Task.

Its working fine for me.But When i make it live on the Production Server IIS 7.Initially it works perfect but after 3-4 hours it automatically stops.I have to restart the Scheduler.
What is the issue.

There is no any exception generated.As i am logging exception to the Log file.But there is nothing written regarding the error from Scheduler.

```
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    // get a scheduler
    IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();

    sched.Start();


    JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("myJob", null, typeof(DumbJob));

    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dt, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "India Standard Time");

    SimpleTrigger trigger2 = new SimpleTrigger("myTrigger",
                            null,
                            DateTime.UtcNow,
                            null,
                            SimpleTrigger.RepeatIndefinitely,
                            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)); 

    sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it's all about Application pool recycling...
(IIS automatically recycles the application pool after a number of requests or a certain time has passed)

More info: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling

Answer (score 0):

Please check your thread count of the Quartz scheduler. 
In web config you  can define the thread count as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="quartz" 
             type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, 
             System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ServerScheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />
  </quartz>
</configuration>
```

I hope this will help you.